# How to merge two pandas DataFrames and keep repeated values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have the following two pandas DataFrames:

**The first one:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','John','John','Paul','Paul','Jimmy'], 'Book':['B1','B2','B1','B3','B4','B3']})
╔═══════╦══════╗
║ Name  ║ Book ║
╠═══════╬══════╣
║ John  ║ B1   ║
║ John  ║ B2   ║
║ John  ║ B1   ║
║ Paul  ║ B3   ║
║ Paul  ║ B4   ║
║ Jimmy ║ B3   ║
╚═══════╩══════╝
```

**The second one:**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Paul','Jimmy'], 'Age':[25,18,28]})
╔═══════╦═════╗
║ Name  ║ Age ║
╠═══════╬═════╣
║ John  ║  25 ║
║ Paul  ║  18 ║
║ Jimmy ║  28 ║
╚═══════╩═════╝
```

And I want the result to be:

```
╔═══════╦══════╦═════╗
║ Name  ║ Book ║ Age ║
╠═══════╬══════╬═════╣
║ John  ║ B1   ║  25 ║
║ John  ║ B2   ║  25 ║
║ John  ║ B1   ║  25 ║
║ Paul  ║ B3   ║  18 ║
║ Paul  ║ B4   ║  18 ║
║ Jimmy ║ B3   ║  28 ║
╚═══════╩══════╩═════╝
```

That is, adding the column "Age" to the fist Data Frame using the column "Name" as key and keeping the repeated names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is as simple as:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','John','John','Paul','Paul','Jimmy'], 'Book':['B1','B2','B1','B3','B4','B3']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Paul','Jimmy'], 'Age':[25,18,28]})

df1.merge(df2)

Out[22]: 
    Name Book  Age
0   John   B1   25
1   John   B2   25
2   John   B1   25
3   Paul   B3   18
4   Paul   B4   18
5  Jimmy   B3   28
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `set_index` and `map`:

```
df1['Age'] = df1['Name'].map(df2.set_index('Name')['Age'])
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
    Name Book  Age
0   John   B1   25
1   John   B2   25
2   John   B1   25
3   Paul   B3   18
4   Paul   B4   18
5  Jimmy   B3   28
```

Map will be faster than merge, since we are only mapping a single column.

> %timeit df1['Age'] = df1['Name'].map(df2.set_index('Name')['Age'])
>   1.22 ms ± 34.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
>
> %timeit df1.merge(df2)
>   2.93 ms ± 73.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)